# Simplify without changing the denominator

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have the following expression:

```
    1/2 (-c y - 2/((2 + x) (1 - δ)) + (
    2 (1 + y))/((2 + x + y) (1 - δ))) + 
1/4 (-c x - c y + 
    1/4 (1/(1 - δ) - (2 (1 + x))/((2 + x) (1 - δ))) + 
    1/4 (1/2 (c x + 1/(1 - δ) - (
          2 (1 + x))/((2 + x) (1 - δ))) + 
       1/2 (c y + 1/(1 - δ) - (
          2 (1 + y))/((2 + y) (1 - δ))) - 2/(1 - δ) - 
       2/((2 + x) (1 - δ)) - 2/((2 + y) (1 - δ))) + 
    1/4 (1/2 (-c x - 1/(1 - δ) + (
          2 (1 + x))/((2 + x) (1 - δ))) + 
       1/2 (-c y - 1/(1 - δ) + (
          2 (1 + y))/((2 + y) (1 - δ))) + 2/(1 - δ) + 
       2/((2 + x) (1 - δ)) + 2/((2 + y) (1 - δ))) + (
    2 (1 + x))/((2 + x + y) (1 - δ)) + (
    2 (1 + y))/((2 + x + y) (1 - δ)))
```

I want to simplify without changing the denominator. For example, you see that the terms:

```
-c y; -c x
```

appears many times. Also the term:

```
/((2 + x + y)
```

Also appear many times. I want to simplify those, by taking out. For example:

```
1/2 (-c y - 2/((2 + x) (1 - δ)) + 1/4 (-c x - c y)
```

when simplify, my desired result would have:

```
-3/4 c y
```

How to do that? If I just use simplify for the entire thing, the result will be:

```
-((8 (4 + y (4 + 6 c (-1 + δ)) + 3 c y^2 (-1 + δ)) + 
  x^2 (7 + 16 c (1 + y) (-1 + δ)) + 
  x (30 + 23 y + 4 c (4 + 14 y + 3 y^2) (-1 + δ)) + 
  4 c x^3 (-1 + δ))/(16 (2 + x) (2 + x + y) (-1 + δ)))
```

Which I do not want.

Comment: Have you tried separating your fraction into its numerator and denominator, simplifying the numerator, then reconstituting the fraction? You could perhaps use [`NumeratorDenominator`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumeratorDenominator.html) to get the two, then only `Simplify` the first.

Comment: I used Expand and got what I needed

Answer (score 1):

I used Expand and got what I needed